# InnoDB clustered index performance when using random values as primary key

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

By default, my primary keys of InnoDB storage engines are auto increment integers. In effort, to hide the number of rows in the database, application code implements some random generator for the primary key.

This is an example of typical scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE `MUSIC_LINK` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am reading a book and have just found out, that InnoDB uses clustered index sorted by primary key. In essence, this means that the records in database file are indexed and ordered by the primary key value. This is great, as long as the primary key for next record is always bigger than the last record inserted (this happens by default because of auto-increment constraint).

What happens when the primary key is no longer auto-incremented? In order to keep the file sorted by primary key, there must be lots of rewrites every time a primary key smaller than the biggest primary key is inserted.

Am I misunderstanding how clustered indexes work in InnoDB? because this sounds like a giant performance issue.

Comment: There's no requirement for a PRIMARY KEY to be public

Comment: *"I am reading a book and have just found out, that InnoDB uses clustered index sorted by primary key. In essence, this means that the records in database file are indexed and ordered by the primary key value. "* i think you should read this [Sorted Index Builds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorted-index-builds.html) as i believe it better goes into the details then your book did.

Comment: *"Am I misunderstanding how clustered indexes work in InnoDB? because this sounds like a giant performance issue."* Well InnoDB is in fact to [benchmarked](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/comparing-innodb-to-myisam-performance) to be **much** faster then MyISAM where the clustered index does **not** exists a qoute from the document *"Compared to MyISAM, InnoDB delivered 35x higher throughput on the Read / Write test and 5x higher throughput on the Read-Only test, with 90% scalability across 36 CPU cores."* to bad the whitepaper link isn't correct/available annymore

Comment: @RaymondNijland - "Sorted Index Builds" seems to talk only about "when creating or rebuilding indexes".  I suggest that the typical user `INSERTs` one row at a time (or a few rows).  Only `LOAD DATA`, `ALTER TABLE` and `mysqldump's` delayed addition of indexes lead to this page (I think).

Comment: @RaymondNijland - I suggest that the benchmark you mentioned is cheating a bit.  It is probably testing how fast rows can be inserted into InnoDB vs MyISAM tables, and cranking up the number of connections to the max.  If you need to insert _thousands_ of rows per second, then the benchmark is relevant.  But who inserts that fast?  (And versions newer than 5.5 are probably even better.) ...

Comment: ... MyISAM loses because of "table locking" in a multi-threaded situation.  InnoDB does row locking, and plays special games with `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which would otherwise feel like the same "row" needing to be locked.  Notice how the curve was flattening off for InnoDB at about 36 connections?  Well, the curve starts going _down_ after that.  5.6 and subsequent versions struggled to make the curve flatten out instead of go down.  Phrases like "thurndering herd" and "stumbling over each other" come to mind.

Comment: @RickJames the page ive linked also seams to describe a other situation **index entries were inserted into the B-tree one record at a time using insert APIs**. I assume that same process still exists today or that is how it works for a single INSERT

Comment: @RickJames the horizontal line are CPU cores not connections in the benchmark atleast that is what it said  maybe they are cheating i dont know...Yes InnoDB in MySQL 8 is most likely faster but i could not find anny benchmark that fast.. Yes mine main reason was to show the document was to show that in een multithread situation the clusterd index update in the InnoDB engine has less impact then MyISAM table locking

Comment: @RaymondNijland - 8.0 may be a little faster, and can handle more connections before flattening out.  The main breaking point for random inserts is whether the data fits in the buffer_pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoDB:

With an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `PRIMARY KEY`, the "next" row will be put at the "end" of the BTree that holds the data for the table.  This is efficient, and the "last" block will be updated a lot.

Note:  Blocks are kept in the buffer_pool, to be *eventually* written to disk.

With a "random" PK, such as GUID, UUID, MD5, SHA1, etc, the "next" row to be inserted needs to go into some 'random' place in the BTree that holds the data.  If the buffer_pool is big enough, then the necessary block will still be sitting in it.  So the efficiency is not much different than with AI.

On the other hand, if the data is too big to fit in the buffer_pool (or other activity keeps bumping the blocks out), then an insert will need to fetch the block before modifying it.

If, for example, the table is 20 times as big as can be held in the buffer_pool, then the next random write will have a chance of 1 in 20 of the block being cached.  That is, 95% of the time an `INSERT` has to wait for a disk read.

But...  You prompted a discussion of `INSERTs`.  What about `SELECTs`?  What, if any, pattern is there to the selects?  If it is 'random' anyway, then the type of PK does not matter.  If, on the other hand, the selects tend to reach for "recent" items (eg, news articles), then AI wins for large tables because of the increased likelihood of the desired block being cached.

**Cluster**

A Comment implies some confusion over "cluster/ed/ing".  Some definitions (in a MySQL/MariaDB context):

- A group of servers with identical data, working together.  NDB Cluster vs Galera Cluster vs Clustrix (3rd party offering)
- A "clustered index" is when the *data* is attached to the index.  In InnoDB, the PK is always clustered with the data.  (Note:  MyISAM, and other vendors do not necessarily do this.)
- When records to be fetched are next to each other in the layout on disk (think the PK *or* a secondary index), then those rows are "clustered together".  This is worth noting because fetching one block gets several rows that you need.

So, back to the Comment:

- Jumping around in the `PRIMARY KEY` (due to using what I called a random PK, or due to simply not fetching rows in some relevant order) is stuck with jumping around in the table.
- A UUID has a "sorted order", but it is not useful to much of anything.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. `With a "random" PK, such as GUID, UUID, MD5, SHA1, etc, the "next" row to be inserted needs to go into some 'random' place in the BTree that holds the data` - What bugs me with clustered indexes is that they don't use B-trees. Take a look at this excerpt: `"When a file is organized so that the ordering of data records is the same as or close to the ordering of data entries in some index, we say that the index is clustered."`. Clustered index implies the organization of the file. A sorted organization of the records in the file.

Comment: @sanjihan - I added to my Answer.  Also, where does that second quote come from?  It is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: It's from Database management systems from Ramakrishnan, Raghu; Gehrke, Johannes. Page 277. On a side note.. the best way seems to be to test. Are there some tools that allow me to very quickly write a query and execute it a bunch of times.. possibly using some random generated values? It's not a big deal to write application code, but such tool would speed up testing.

Comment: `"A "clustered index" is when the data is attached to the index. In InnoDB, the PK is always clustered with the data."`- this is how I understand it too.

Comment: In case I did not mention it:  InnoDB indexes use only BTree, Fulltext, or Spatial formats for indexing.  No Hash, Isam, Bit, etc.

Comment: I did not know that. I haven't made to fulltext and spatial formats so far in the book.
I've run some tests and I can confirm that performance increase when using auto increment primary key is negligible. For 100k row insertions, it took roughly 17 seconds in both scenarios.